# Maven bundles multiple versions of same libraries in WAR

Tags: maven

I got NoSuchMethodError exceptions when running test from Maven build. I realized Maven bundles multiple versions of same libraries in war (some transitive dependencies has different versions). Is it default behaviour? I fail too see how could someone want it. Also, I found that exclusion tag can't have version (or range) so I can't exclude conflicting version. Is there any way to prevent Maven from adding multiple versions of same library to war? Thank you.

EDIT: Yeah, I can exclude it and depend on it in my POM. But it's far from elegant solution (can cause problems with changes in upstream).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the assembly-plugin to exclude some dependencies. But that would be the same as excluding duplicates with different versions in the dependencies section. So I highly recommend to exclude the duplicates in the dependencies section. Also your project might lack a proper dependency management. If you use this correctly, you have all exclusions in the same pom.